# Perturbation theory of eigenvalues - Effects of degeneracy/ multiplicity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

In Quantum mechanics Schrödinger's perturbation theory is very important (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29)) which deals with perturbation of the discrete spectrum of a self-adjoint operator.

Where can I find a mathematical description which covers the physical argument when considering eigenvalues of higher multiplicity? One often calls it degeneracy.

In Kato's Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators Chapter 2 one can find the perturbation of simple eigenvalues with a mention of the notations of quantum mechanics.
Surely, in this chapter there is the degenerated case as well, but I find only formulas about the mean value of the eigenvalue. I want to know how the individual eigenvalues behave, like in the [Stark effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect).

Does anybody know a standard reference?

Answer (score 3):

Kato's theory has been extended to include degenerate eigenvalues by Hunziker and Pillet, [Degenerate asymptotic perturbation theory](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103940282) (1983).

> These beautiful results [of Kato and others] are not quite
>   satisfactory in one respect: they suffer from the unnatural assumption
>   that the unperturbed eigenvalue is non-degenerate (or, in some cases,
>   that its degeneracy is lifted in first order). Our aim is to remove
>   restrictions of this kind and to develop asymptotic perturbation
>   theory in the general degenerate case to any possible order